# How to pass the array value from one function to another function and send it to view the page using Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting array value from model and that value I have to pass the other function

**Controller**

**First function**

```
public function example_from_view(){
 $int_id = $this->session->userdata['int_url_id']['int_id'];
$result['data']=$this->formbuilder_Model->check_example_form_builder_fields($int_id);
print_r($result['data']); //I have to pass this array to second function so I tried $this->new_example_added($result);
 $this->load->view('user-example-form',$result);//passing elements to the view page
    }
```

**Second function**

```
public function new_example_added($result)
{
print_r($result['data']);
$this->load->view('user-example-form', $result);
}
```

**View**

```
foreach ($data as $key) {
 echo $exp_fields_name=$key->fields_name;
}
```

But I am getting in view page `undefined variable: data and Undefined variable: result`.
I want to use without a session. Would you help me out in this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change **First function** code

```
public function example_from_view(){

      if(isset($this->input->post('SUBMIT_BUTTON_NAME'))){
         //do your validation here
      }
      $int_id = $this->session->userdata['int_url_id']['int_id'];
      $data = $this->formbuilder_Model->check_example_form_builder_fields($int_id);
      //print_r($result['data']); //I have to pass this array to second function so I tried $this->new_example_added($result);
      $result['data'] = $data;
      $this->load->view('user-example-form',$result);//passing elements to the view page
}
```

**Remove this function,**

```
public function new_example_added($result)
{
  //print_r($result['data']);
  $data['data'] = $result;
  $this->load->view('user-example-form', $data);
}
```

Comment: I am getting Missing argument 1 in second function

Comment: How do you call second function new_example_added() ? show me little more code.

Comment: Actually  I am passing the result to view in the first function. There is a form in view(user-example-form) after clicked on submit button It will check the validation which is on the second function(new_example_added) but I am getting the undefined variable: data in view after clicked on button

Comment: You don't need second function to check validation of form. just check my edited answer

Comment: @NarendraVerma may be add `= ''` like `new_example_added($result = '')` then var dump the result

Comment: @wolfgang1983, i tried but I am getting error in view  Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

Comment: If you don't want to post your form in first function then you should select data again in second function. and remove argument ($result). @NarendraVerma

Comment: Yes, Mr.Naim, It's working but I have on doubt. After success how to redirect on other page,

Comment: You can use this function redirect('URL', 'refresh')

Answer (score 0):

I would recomment that you should not load the view from 1st function. You should just pass the `$result` array to the other function `new_example_added` and then load view from there. Which is done in correct way.

Comment: Actually the thing is that I am passing result data to view the page in the first function. There is a form in view after clicked on submit button It will check the validation which is on the second function but I am getting the undefined variable: data in view after clicked on button

Comment: So the errors you mentioned `undefined variable: data and Undefined variable: result` is on view file or in controller?

Comment: undefined variable: data, I am getting in view page after clicking don button for submitting

Answer (score 0):

Its Very Simple 
Add Second Function in First Function like this ..

IN the contorller

```
class Test extends CI_Controller{
  public function one(){
     $data['result'] = array(
        'one' => '1',
        'two' => '2',
        'three' => '3'
    );
    #calling Second function
    $data['view'] = $this->second($data);
    $this->load->view('testview', $data);
  }
  public function second($data)
  {
    $data = array(
        'four' => '4',
        'five' => '5',
        'six' => '6'
    );
    return $data;
  }
}
```

Then in view page

```
foreach($result as $res):
   echo $res."<br/>";
endforeach;
foreach($view as $res):
    echo $res."<br/>";
endforeach;
```